# Word vba jump to next page

Tags: vba, ms-word

Okay,

so for my apprenticeship I need to keep record of what I do everyday. Since this is going to be a long doc, I wrote a VBA script which already writes stuff that stays the same, like the date, in there.

Problem is, the format is supposed to be one week per page. Means, when I arrive at saturday, the script would have to jump to the beginning of the next page(and probably fill the resulting space with paragraphs). And I have absolutely no clue if there is any function that could help me with that. I think there should be one tho, this doesn't Sound like a too exotic Problem.

Now this is no crucial problem, but it's annoying nonetheless and I'd like to know if there is any solution for this. Research so far didn't do the trick either.

Have some code if that helps understanding. Ist basically about the commented part:

```
For i = InitDate To endDate
jump:
  If CurrentDate = endDate Then GoTo EndSub
    x = x + 1
    strWeekday = weekday(CurrentDate, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
    txtStr = Format(CurrentDate, "dddddd")
     With Selection
     .Font.Bold = True
     .Font.Underline = True
     .TypeText Text:=txtStr
     .TypeParagraph
    If x = 4 Then GoTo Thursday
    If x = 5 Then GoTo Friday
   'If x = 6 Then GoTo NewSheet
    If x = 6 Then x = 0

    .TypeParagraph
    End With
CurrentDate = CurrentDate + 1

Next i
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46689359/edit) to include more information.  As braX noted, what have you tried?  Did your "research so far" include Google and MSDN?  And have you consided manual page breaks? ;)

Comment: Added the code so far. Yea Manual page breaks would've been my Workaround, but there has to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).InsertAfter ChrW(12)
```

will insert a hard page break at the end of your text.  (Or, in general, `r.InsertAfter ChrW(12)` for a `Range` variable `r`.  Then you can carry on from there!

#### Edit

Now that you've added code, I can show you more.  However, since you didn't include all the code, I can't provide something that will run as is.   Also, I think you can replace `CurrentDate` with `i` (or vice versa).

```
For i = InitDate To endDate
jump:
  If CurrentDate = endDate Then GoTo EndSub
    x = x + 1
    strWeekday = weekday(CurrentDate, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
    txtStr = Format(CurrentDate, "dddddd")
    With Selection
         .Font.Bold = True
         .Font.Underline = True
         .TypeText Text:=txtStr
         .TypeParagraph
    End With

     ' ** By the way, I would suggest you not GoTo out of a With block - that strikes me as likely to cause confusion later on.
     If x = 4 Then GoTo Donnerstag  
     If x = 5 Then GoTo Freitag
     'If x = 6 Then GoTo NewSheet
     If x = 6 Then       ' ** Try this
         Selection.InsertAfter ChrW(12)
         Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     End If
     If x = 6 Then x = 0

     Selection.TypeParagraph
     CurrentDate = CurrentDate + 1
Next i
```

Comment: What does the Parameter 12 stand for?

Comment: A manual page break.  Word uses some of the non-ASCII characters for special codes, e.g., 5 for a comment mark and 12 for a page break.  [Find-dialog codes](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7) like `^12` also use those numbers.